# Excluding a function when deploying firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 environment: development and production.
In the development environment I would like to have a couple of extra functions which due to their nature **cannot** be deployed to prod.

How can I achieve this without having two almost identical cloud function files?

I know one can name the functions when deploying them, but I cannot find a way to exclude a function.

Comment: What is your current deployment strategy? If you are using `gcloud functions deploy` I think each function is specified individually, so you would exclude functions from production simply by...not deploying them.

Comment: You are right. The docs recommends to deploy functions individually when the number of functions exceed 5: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting as community wiki as per @Myk Willis, if you're using gcloud functions deploy, each function is specified individually. Exclude functions from production simply by not deploying them.

As per the OP, when using Firebase tools, the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#deploy_functions) recommends to deploy functions individually when the number of functions exceed 5.

This command explicitly specifies the functions to be deployed on the project:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:yourFunction1,functions:yourFuntion2
```

Comment: What about when you need to deploy all functions to deploy your env variables? e.g. firebase deploy --only functions